# Show that $f_n$ converges to $f(t)=e^{-t^2/4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

Let

$$f(t):=e^{-t^2/4}, \ \ \ t\ge0$$ (which is decreasing and uniformly continuous)

and
$$f_n(t) := \sum_{k=0}^{n 2^n} \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{4} \exp \left( \frac{(k+1)}{2^n} \right)^2 \right] 1_{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}(t).$$

How can I show that

$$f_n(t)\le f(t) \ \ \ \forall t\ge 0$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(t)=f(t)$$

Comment: Are you sure you copied the formula for $f_n(t)$ correctly?

Comment: @Christoph Yes, I copy pasted it

Comment: If we express $\exp\left[-\frac 1 4\exp\left(-\frac{(k+1)}{2^n}\right)^2\right]$ in terms of $t$ at the end of the interval it is used on, that is, at $t=(k+1)2^{-n}$, we get $\exp\left[-\frac 1 4 \exp(-t)^2\right]$, which is not quite $e^{-t^2/4}$.

Comment: @Christoph True... Do you know how $f_n$ could look like in order to fulfill the 2 requirements above?

Comment: I would have expected $\exp\left[-\frac 1 4\left(\frac{(k+1)}{2^n}\right)^2\right]$ instead of $\exp\left[-\frac 1 4\exp\left(-\frac{(k+1)}{2^n}\right)^2\right]$.

Comment: @Christoph Okay, can you show me how to prove $f_n(t)\le f(t)$ and $f_n(t) \to f(t)$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there was a misprint and it should be

$$f_n(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n 2^n} \exp \left[ - \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{(k+1)}{2^n} \right)^2 \right] 1_{[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}(t).$$

Note that this is just another way to write the step function

$$f_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
\exp \left[ - \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{(k+1)}{2^n} \right)^2 \right] 
& \text{if $t\in I_{n,k}$ for some $0\le k\le n 2^n$}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$

where the intervals are given by $I_{n,k} = \left[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{(k+1)}{2^n}\right)$.

Using $f(t) = e^{-t^2/4}$ we can also write this as
$$
f_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
f\left(\frac{(k+1)}{2^n} \right) & \text{if $t\in I_{n,k}$ for some $0\le k\le n 2^n$}, \\
0 & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$

Hence $f_n(t)$ is obtained on $\left[0, n+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\bigcup_{k=0}^{n2^n} I_{n,k}$ by evaluating $f$ at the right bound of the interval containing $t$.

Since $f$ is decreasing, we immediately get that $f_n(t) \le f(t)$ whenever $t$ is in one of the intervals: for $t\in I_{n,k}$ we have $t < \frac{k+1}{2^n}$, hence
$$
f_n(t) = f\left( \frac{k+1}{2^n}\right) \le f(t).
$$
Beyond the intervals, that is for $t\ge n+\frac{1}{2^n}$, we have
$$
f_n(t) = 0 \le f(t).
$$

If we look at the left bound of the intervals instead, we obtain an upper bound. That is, let $t\in I_{n,k}$, then $t\ge \frac{k}{2^n}$ so that $k\le t2^n$ and we get
$$
f_n(t) = f\left(\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right) \ge f\left(\frac{t2^n+1}{2^n}\right)
= f\left(t+\frac{1}{2^n}\right).
$$

In summary, for $0\le t < n+\frac{1}{2^n}$ we have
$$
f\left(t+\frac{1}{2^n}\right) \le f_n(t) \le f(t).
$$

Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ and using continuity of $f$, the squeeze theorem implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t) = f(t)
$$
for all $t\ge 0$.